# Parallel Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

[image]

Can anyone tell me how it works?

In my opinion when U+ = U- the voltage Uo is constant no matter of the load resistor(R5). But this is only if U+=U-.

Answer (score 5):

It's a shunt voltage regulator. The op-amp applies just enough gate drive to the MOSFET to keep both its inputs at the same voltage level and, in doing so regulates the voltage \$U_0\$ by shunting current through the MOSFET. Negative feedback occurs because of the inversion due to the MOSFET.

R5 is probably present to share the load thus taking some power dissipation away from the MOSFET. R5 also provides some loop stabilization in that the gain of the MOSFET is brought to less than unity and there should be little chance that the circuit turns into an oscillator although stranger things do happen.

Comment: It's not a very good regulator since the reference voltage is proportional to the unregulated input voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton that's a bit of an assumption about the net labelled as 12 volts. There's nothing in the question that suggests it is unregulated and, for instance it may be designed this way i.e. it is a tracking shunt regulator.

Comment: Well it's true that this might be designed for a case where line regulation isn't needed or even wanted, but generally if you just throw something out as a "voltage regulator", line regulation is going to be one of the first specs potential users ought to ask about.

Comment: I'll revise my previous statement: This is not a very good general-purpose regulator since the reference voltage is proportional to the unregulated input voltage.

Answer (score 3):

This arrangement is usually called a "shunt" regulator as it shunts current around the load to pull the voltage down to the desired level. In this case the regulator will maintain an adjustable constant voltage on the load, R5.

Your understanding is correct. The voltage at \$ U_O \$ can be controlled.

- With Q1 turned off \$ U_O = \frac {12 \times R5}{R5 + RB} = \frac {12 \times 5} {5 + 5} = 6 \; V \$. Note that in this case 50% of the power is lost as heat in RB.
- With Q1 fully on R3 is in parallel with R5 giving 2.5 Ω so \$ U_O = \frac {12 \times 2.5} {5 + 2.5} = 4 \; V \$. In this case 66% of the power is lost to RB and R3.

Shunt or parallel regulators are not popular because of their inefficiency.

> In my opinion when U+ = U- the voltage Uo is constant no matter of the load resistor (R5). But this is only if U+=U-.

Correct. If the the output voltage rises above setpoint the op-amp will turn on Q1 some more to pull it back down again. Conversely, if \$ U_O \$ falls Q1 will be turned off somewhat to restore equilibrium.

---

> Can I ask you why only when U+=U- then Uo is constant no matter the load, what is the relationship between U+ and U-?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbMdYw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simplified schematic.*

A few things to clarify first.

- For this circuit to be stable we need to apply some negative feedback. This is understandably confusing in this case because it appears to be fed back to the non-inverting input. We'll explain that in a moment.
- Remember that the open-loop gain of an op-amp is very high. I can't remember what it is for an LM358 but let's say it's 1,000,000 (1 million). That means that if the non-inverting input is 1 µV above the inverting input that the output will swing positive by 1µ x 1M = 1 V.

Now to the operation:

- We can replace R2 and RV1 with "Vref", our (scaled) desired output voltage setpoint.
- Now what happens if Vfb is a little higher than Vref? OA1 output will start to rise, M1 will be turned on a little more and shunt some current through R3. This will cause Uo to fall slightly and Vfb will fall proportionally. The system will stabilise when Vfb is very close to Vref.
- If the output voltage is a bit low then Vfb will be a bit less than Vref. This will reduce the output voltage of OA1, turning off the M1 - R3 shunt a little and allow Uo to rise back to the desired position.
- In this case M1 is providing the "negative" component of the feedback. The more you turn it on the lower the output and feedback voltage.

Notes:

This circuit doesn't look *very* good.

- There is no op-amp decoupling capacitor.
- Vref will vary with +12 supply. If there is ripple on this then there will be ripple on Uo. If the +12 supply droops under load then Vref will too.

Comment: Can I ask you why only when U+=U- then Uo is constant no matter the load, what is the relationship between U+ and U-?

Comment: See the update.